# Vue 3 + Firebase onAuthStateChanged mount

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuejs3

I am following a tutorial for Vue that uses the following code:

```
let app
auth.onAuthStateChanged(() => {
  if (!app) {
    app = new Vue({
      router,
      store,
      render: h => h(App)
    }).$mount('#app')
  }
})
```

This is supposed to make sure that Firebase loads the authState before mounting the app, if a user reloads the page.

However, I am using Vue 3 and the thus I can't initialize via `new Vue()` anymore, as you have to use `createApp` now.
I'm initializing & mounting my app the following way:

```
createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount('#app')
```

Unfortunately, I am lost on how I can make sure that the DB still initializes the same way, and I was unable to find a proper solution (spent the last hour on google & SO).

Any help is highly appreciated, maybe I am just missing a simple concept for promises or something similar.

Thank you very much, stay healthy!

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you mean but. `Vue.createApp` also returns a app instance and you can use it in the above example you have provided. check here https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/instance.html#application-component-instances

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Vue 3's `createApp` is same as Vue 2's `new Vue()`, returning Vue app instance:

```js
let app;

auth.onAuthStateChanged(() => {
  if (!app) {
    app = createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount('#app')
  }
})
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much! That's much simpler than expected, I must have had a little roadblock in my head there.

Comment: Works excellent with Vue 3 and Firebase 9

Comment: @degergio I have Vue 3 and Firebase 9 too. How do you handle extracting tokens and user data for use in the app with the above code?

Answer (score 0):

this might be late reply but i find this bad approach instead of not mounting the app , ( on slow network your user will have a white screen , the app might never mount , so move the logic to App.vue

```
<template>
  <div v-if="isLoading" class="loading-screen">
    {{ timedout ? "Sorry please check your network" : "Loading..." }}
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref, onMounted } from "vue";
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/auth";

import { useAuthStore } from "./stores/user";
const auth = firebase.auth();
const authStore = useAuthStore()

export default defineComponent({
  name: "App",
  setup() {
    const isLoading = ref(true);
    let timedout = ref(false)
    onMounted(() => {
      let timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        timedout.value = true
      }, 5000)
      const router = useRouter();
      const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        clearTimeout(timeout)
        isLoading.value = false;
        if (user) {
          authStore.fbUser = user;
        } else {
          router.push("/auth");
        }
      });
      return () => {
        unsubscribe();
      };
    });

    return {
      isLoading,
      timedout
    };
  },
});
</script>

<style>
.loading-screen {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-size: 24px;
}
</style>
```